# VPS minecraft Putty

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have turned on minecraft in my VPS via PuTTY.

```
screen sh minecraft.sh
```

How can I stop this process and how can I go there so that I can use all the commands?

I am very new to PuTTY and this.

Comment: You could change the shell to RemoteToolKit, which uses Telnet. It would be easier to telnet to it. Also, stupid question, but you are using a Unix-based operating system, right?

Comment: While this question is on-topic here, you might have better luck getting a good answer on one of the other Stack Exchange sits ([SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) if that's what you're using).  Just don't double post.

Comment: Thanks for the advise @MBraedley but my question is anwered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PuTTY, if I remember right, is basically an emulator for Unix terminals. In PuTTY, you have the `screen` command which is wrapping `sh minecraft.sh`.

Try getting the process id of the screen:

> screen -ls

This should get you a list of running screens and their process IDs. Odds are one of them will have your minecraft shell.

Open that screen:

> screen -r [screen PID]

and you'll be in the minecraft server console.

Now that you're in, you can use the minecraft server commands like `stop` to stop your server.

If you want to leave the screen but keep the server running, type `CTRL-a CTRL-d` to exit.

Hope that helps!

Comment: If you are in the console, typing `/stop` would actually make the server interpret it as `/stop` because anything entered in console already has a `/` in front of it.

Comment: @JeffreyLin You're right. Fixed.